# Column Type Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am looking for a way that I can find out the type of a field.

For example I have a table called `users` with the following:

```
+---------+---------+---------------------+
|   id    |  name   |      datetime       |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
|   1     |  bob    | 2015-08-11 12:00:00 |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

`id` being a type of `int`, `name` being a `varchar` and `datetime` being `datetime`.

I have a model for example:

```
$model = Users::model()->findByPk(1);
```

I then need to feed it an attribute like `getColumnType($model->id)`

I have seen in the documentation we have http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbSchema which has a method `getColumnType` but I am struggling to see how this works. Currently I am trying like so:

```
$model = Users::model()->findByPk(1);
CDbSchema::getColumnType($model->id);
```

However this results in the error `Property "UsersController.columnTypes" is not defined.`

I have created a public property in the Controller, which resolves the error, but I am still not getting the result required.

At the top of the models that have been generated we can see

```
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property datetime $datetime
```

Therefore there must be a way to retrieve this info, or even modify the model generation code to create a method to retrieve this info.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some unknown reason as soon as I ask a question Google seems to decide it will give me what I want. In order to find the column type you can do the following:

```
$column = 'id';
$type = Users::model()->getMetaData()->columns[$column]->type;
print_r($type);
```

The will give you the column type, however, if your column is a `varchar`, the result of `$type` will be `string`, there is however another property `dbType` which returns `varchar(200)`. Here is some of the output of `$type`

```
 [id] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
    (
        [name] => id
        [rawName] => `id`
        [allowNull] => 
        [dbType] => int(11)
        [type] => integer
        [defaultValue] => 
        [size] => 11
        [precision] => 11
        [scale] => 
        [isPrimaryKey] => 1
        [isForeignKey] => 
        [autoIncrement] => 1
        [comment] => 
        [_e:CComponent:private] => 
        [_m:CComponent:private] => 
    )

[name] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
    (
        [name] => name
        [rawName] => `name`
        [allowNull] => 
        [dbType] => varchar(200)
        [type] => string
        [defaultValue] => 
        [size] => 200
        [precision] => 200
        [scale] => 
        [isPrimaryKey] => 
        [isForeignKey] => 
        [autoIncrement] => 
        [comment] => 
        [_e:CComponent:private] => 
        [_m:CComponent:private] => 
    )
```